# "Unable to connect to the remote server" FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ftp

I've been all around SO and Google to track the source of that WebException.

Solution to my problem was changing Uri host from domain name to IP representation ex. "ftp://mysite.website" to "ftp://111.111.111.111". Did not find that kind of hint of SO so posting it as a part of my question.

My question might be vague but...

1/ Why overnight I had to implement that change (code was working with domain name in Uri for a long time and also I'm still able to connect to FTP vie ex. Filezilla).

2/ Is there a decent resource/book on FTP protocol (general or asp.net related) that would help me get better understanding on how it works so it will be easier to debug that kind of issues?

Comment: the domain name for mysite.website may have been expired and it could have been deleted from DNS servers. Can you do an nslookup to see if the domain name resolves to that IP address?

Comment: #Oguz Ozgul Domain is not expired. After doing nslookup I realized that IP address that I'm using to connect to FTP is different from http://mysite.website IP. It makes sense but then why FileZilla is able to connect to server with domain name and WebRequest is not...

Comment: FileZilla may have cached the IP address for the host name. What IP address FileZilla ils connecting to? The same IP address you have updated for the WebRequest, or the IP address returned by the NSLookup?

Comment: That's the updated IP address used in code

Comment: Then what server is at the other end of the IP address returned by the DNS servers (nslookup) ? Note: Mistakenly added as answer then deleted..